# Find largest independent set in list

Tags: list, optimization

I have python lists like follows

```
>>>[[2, 0, 10], [2, 0, 11], [2, 1, 12], [2, 1, 13], [4, 3, 5], [4, 3, 7], [7, 6, 8], [7, 6, 10], [10, 9, 2], [10, 9, 11], [13, 14, 15]]
>>>[[0, 1, 3], [0, 1, 6], [3, 2, 0], [3, 2, 6], [3, 4, 5]]
```

I want to extract largest list set containing uncommon values. For example, for latter list, the largest independent set should be `[[0, 1, 6], [3, 4, 5]]`, whereas for the former, it should be `[[2, 0, 12], [4, 3, 5], [7, 6, 8], [10, 9, 11], [13, 14, 15]]`. It may be similar with maximum independent set problem, but I have no idea about this as I know nothing about graphs. So any suggestion to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set Packing is NP-complete, There are some solutions using Graph Theory, If you don't really care about performance, you can try brute force or some greedy solution (comparing all possible solutions).

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Solved using brute force with some constraints learned from the data. I think the procedure is more similar with dynamic programming. Thanks for your advice.